# How can I run a simple function on Core Data results

Tags: core-data, swiftui

Apologies if this is a very basic question, I'm just learning how to use Core Data.

I'm trying to run a simple function (`Text("\(items.timestamp.count)")`) on the data Apple gives you by default (a list of items with just one attribute: `timestamp`). However, I keep getting the error **"Value of type 'FetchedResults' has no member 'timestamp"**.

Can anyone explain why this happens? When the `timestamp` attribute is accessed within the `ForEach` loop automatically provided by Apple, everything seems to works fine.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(items.timestamp.count)")
        
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
            }
        }
    }



}

private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    return formatter
}()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because items (aka  FetchedResults) is an array of item. So it can contain multiple returned Items.

The ForEach is working because a ForEach by nature iterates through the array and displays each one.

if you'd like to just display the count of items then remove the "timestamp" part:

```
Text("\(items.count)")
```

if you'd like to display the timestamp then you'd need to specify which item in the array you want to display the timestamp for. so to display the timestamp for the first item in the array then you can do:

```
 Text("\(items[0].timestamp ?? Date())")
```

(note that if there are no items in the database then you will get today's date. Also it's more common to use a list and ForEach which will display all records in a list including timestamps (like you have in the rest of Apple's boilerplate code))